# Play framework and scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I am new to web development and i am trying to use play framework, however when i try to use the command: avtivator new to create a new project i receive the following error:

```
    $ activator new
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at activator.ActivatorCli$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcI$sp(ActivatorCli.sca
la:21)
        at activator.ActivatorCli$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ActivatorCli.scala:19)
        at activator.ActivatorCli$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ActivatorCli.scala:19)
        at activator.ActivatorCli$.withContextClassloader(ActivatorCli.scala:179
)
        at activator.ActivatorCli$.apply(ActivatorCli.scala:19)
        at activator.ActivatorLauncher.run(ActivatorLauncher.scala:28)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: BAD URI: file://c:/Users/Euaggelos/Docume
nts/Weather-fi2/Weather-fi2

        at activator.properties.ActivatorProperties.uriToFilename(ActivatorPrope
rties.java:106)
        at activator.properties.ActivatorProperties.ACTIVATOR_HOME_FILENAME(Acti
vatorProperties.java:113)
        at activator.properties.ActivatorProperties.ACTIVATOR_TEMPLATE_LOCAL_REP
O(ActivatorProperties.java:179)
        at activator.UICacheHelper$.<init>(UICacheHelper.scala:31)
        at activator.UICacheHelper$.<clinit>(UICacheHelper.scala)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
        at activator.properties.ActivatorProperties.uriToFilename(ActivatorPrope
rties.java:101)
        ... 19 more
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

I have windows 8.1 64 bit, i want to be able to use Intellije, i have installed java, sbt and scala

```
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)

Scala code runner version 2.11.4 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: does the folder `c:/Users/Euaggelos/Docume
nts/Weather-fi2/Weather-fi2` exist?  Is that where you are executing the `activator new` command?

Comment: Yes it exists and yes i have the activator in that folder when i run it.

Comment: Looks like this might be a project with `activator` in the windows bash:  https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/648.  They claim that this is fixed on master, if you want to give that a try.

Comment: This has a solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710316/intellij-and-sbt-0-13-5-uri-has-an-authority-component