# InteliJ Play project import error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I created a brand new empty Scala Play Framework project with `activator new` and selecting `6) scala-play`. On my fresh install of IntelliJ 64, I am getting this confusing error when trying to open/import the project:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.sbt$Classpaths$$bootRepository(Defaults.scala:1758)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$appRepositories$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1729)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$appRepositories$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1729)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.appRepositories(Defaults.scala:1729)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$41.apply(Defaults.scala:1102)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$41.apply(Defaults.scala:1102)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:175)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:135)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:69)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:78)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:74)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Invalid response.
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this or what it even means? The play project compiles fine and runs without issues and all the software has been freshly re-installed, so this is likely something specific to IntelliJ.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710316/intellij-and-sbt-0-13-5-uri-has-an-authority-component#comment49485190_30710316

Comment: in the last line say that "Use 'last' for the full log" did you check that?

Comment: @Roman - Ah. Maybe. I'll have a look.

Comment: @saman - I'm pretty sure that's the data it was referring to. This is coming from a file of the same name (though I can't seem to recall where I found it anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that erasing the `C:\Users\<username>\.sbt` folder solved the problem (sbt will recreate it).

As @Roman suggested, this is probably linked to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710316/intellij-and-sbt-0-13-5-uri-has-an-authority-component#comment49485190_30710316), but the suggested solution did not work for me as I didn't even have the `.sbt/repositories` sub-directory. On the up side, I haven't had any more issues since.