# Trouble when opening SBT by Windows 7 console

Tags: java, windows, scala, playframework, sbt

SBT installed in Win 7 that I have run it by 'cmd' occurs the following error:

---

```
C:\Users\goularta>sbt
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.sbt$Classpaths$$bootRepository(Defaults.scala:1758)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$appRepositories$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1729)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$appRepositories$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1729)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.appRepositories(Defaults.scala:1729)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$41.apply(Defaults.scala:1102)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$41.apply(Defaults.scala:1102)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:175)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:135)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:69)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:78)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:74)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.

Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? i
```

---

somebody have a idea of what can be the trouble?

Comment: Possible duplicate of thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366270/what-does-uri-has-an-authority-component-mean

Comment: No! My problem is when you start SBT by 'cmd' the Win7 ... yet there is no source code.

Comment: What is the result of execution last?

Comment: Try to rename your local ivy directory to something else, could be a bad jar in your filesystem

Comment: in the last command, no matter the choice, SBT always closes.

Comment: i will try use your the last suggestion

Comment: @d1egoaz 's suggestion worked for me

Answer (score 0):

As you've tagged your question with playframework it's probably duplicate of [Intellij and sbt 0.13.5 "URI has an authority component"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710316/intellij-and-sbt-0-13-5-uri-has-an-authority-component/30725096)

Check you `repository`file in `C:\Users\profilename\.sbt\repositories`
and add a third slash to the file protocol. E.g.

```
[repositories]
   local
   activator-launcher-local: file:///${activator.local.repository-${activator.home-${user.home}/.activator}/repository}, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
   activator-local: file:///${activator.local.repository-//D:/.../activator-1.3.4/repository}, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
   maven-central
   ...
```

Note: every time you start Activator UI or create a new project via Activator the file-URIs are changed back.

See https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/1033 for the related bug entry.